# Cant use margin command in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to use margin in html but when im writing margin it doesn't auto complete and It doesn't work even if I type
here is my code;

```
<html lang="tr">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GAMEBLOG</title>
</head> 
<body>
    STYLE="margin:30px"
    <hr   align="left" color="Red" size="60"width="1475"> 
   <center><font  face="papyrus" size="12" color="maroon">   <span><b>Gameblog News</b></span></font></center> 
   <p>
<center><h1><font face="Arial">En hızlı büyüyen kara delik bulundu: <br>
     'Her saniye Dünya büyüklüğünde kütle yutuyor'</font> </h1></center>
   </p>
   <hr color="Lightgray" width="500"size="3">
 <center><img src="C:\Users\Samet\Desktop/kara.png"  width="400" height="400">   
 </center>  

 <b>Avustralyalı astronomların liderliğini yaptığı bilim insanlarından oluşan bir ekip, son dokuz milyar yılın en hızlı büyüyen kara deliğini keşfettiklerini açıkladı.</b>


   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `font` and `center` tags are deprecated and should not be used and `b` tags should not be used to make things bold. pretty much all of your attributes are deprecated or invalid for the element (eg align, color, size, width, height, etc) - you should be using css for these things

Comment: @samet kahraman If you really want to delete the question, there is an extra button for it.

Comment: i already knew but it says You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `style` a HTML tag. For exemple, if you want to put margin on the body, you have to do this :

```
<body style="margin:30px;">
// Your code
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks.When I looked at the answer, I said how simple I made a mistake, but I am new to this so there is nothing to do.

Comment: No problem. Welcome! You can accept the answer if you want. Upvote and downvote also exist for each question and answer.